# Optimize and Scale my Webservers (Nginx + Gunicorn + Django stack)

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

We have a web server setup running Nginx and Gunicorn which runs a Django application. There have been times that we received high load and got a lot of 5XXs. To get rid of that immediately we increased the number of servers 5 times and restarted all Gunicorn workers. 
Now, our servers are still not used optimally, CPU is around 10-15% max used and same for the memory (20-30%). 
So, this is not a permanent solution and it also incurs us downtime and high costs if we go with larger and more number of servers.

To research this we started with **load tests.**

When we do a load test we start getting 5xx errors even when the resources on the server are barely used.

## **LOAD TEST RESULTS**

**Load Test 1**

**Resources**: 1 ELB 1 server with Nginx and 4 workers of gunicorn running in virtual env serving Django.

Ran load test using Locust which has a full workflow of what a user would do after getting into the app.

1000 Users, Ramp up 10

**Requests Per Second** (Before Failure): 120
**Max CPU** = 45 % on CloudWatch, on server fluctuating up to 100%
Memory did not get used more than 2 GB after load test started. Server has 8 GB Memory (RAM)

Suddenly I start getting errors. Started getting gateway timeouts, cannot connect to backend server. There were AWS ELB 5xx as well and then the server also went out of service.

**Load Test 2**

**Resources**: 4 servers, 1 ELB, with Nginx and 4 workers of Gunicorn running on each server in virtualenv serving Django.

1000 Users, Ramp up 10

34 RPS, 11 % Failure rate suddenly and then stopped getting 200. 
ELB servers out of service. Around 29000 total requests, 2965 had failed I believe and then all started failing. The size of requests around 140688 Bytes.Started getting gateway timeouts, cannot connect to the backend server.

CPU again did not go above 20 % utilization.
Memory did not get used more than 2 GB after load test started. Server has 8 GB Memory (RAM)

Load Test 3
**Resources**: 11 servers under one ELB

Went till Fluctuated from 80-200 RPS (requests per second)
Started getting gateway timeouts, cannot connect to backend server
Servers got unhealthy

CPU again did not go above 20 % utilization.
Memory did not get used more than 2 GB after load test started. Server has 8 GB Memory (RAM)

**Load Test 4**

Resources: 40 servers
Results on similar lines.

### Tweaking Starts

### **Things I have configured on Nginx**

Allowed to accept 1500 connections per worker and fine tuned fds, cache, gzip, worker limit etc.

**Made the following changes to Nginx conf:**

```
Nginx worker processes are set to auto which is okay, I guess.
Nginx keepalive timeout is 65 which is high. 

open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
open_file_cache_valid 30s;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors on;

tcp_nopush=on     Send all the response in a simple packet.

keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
send_timeout 10;
sendfile on;    sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
worker_rlimit_nofile 10000;
```

**Gzip settings as follows:**

```
gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

Could it be that my Nginx is accepting connections and Gunicorn not being optimized is not being able to process those requests?

### **System Level**

Also, should I make system level changed like:
sysctl net.core.somaxconn=1024 ? For now, it is 128. Is that the limiting problem?

**Gunicorn Command we are using**

```
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  -b 127.0.0.1:8000 \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --log-level=info \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --timeout $TIMEOUT \
  --backlog=2048
```

Workers on m4.large is 4. Timeout and other variable values:

```
SOCKFILE=/home/ubuntu/run/gunicorn.sock    # using this unix socket
USER=ubuntu                                   # the user to run as
GROUP=ubuntu                                  # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=4                              # how many workerprocesses should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=haptik_api.wsgi               # WSGI module name
PORT=8000
TIMEOUT=300
```

## FINAL PROBLEMS

1. I want to know how and what parameters I can change in Gunicorn so that I am well utilizing my resources. My servers are 4 core 8 GB RAM for now.
2. How can I make Gunicorn use more memory and CPU so that the servers are use optimally. What all can I tweak?
3. Is there system level tweak required? like sysctl
4. I have even tried with m4.xlarge and m4.2xlarge and t2.medium (with 4 times the count of servers)
5. Can AWS ELB be the problem too? That it can't handle those requests and can't add to surge queue?
6. How do I optimize my Nginx + Gunicorn + Django nonrel to accept more connections and perform better and also optimize resource utilization?
7. What should I set as SCALING POLICY for the servers? CPU? Memory? Network? or anything else. (Problem also is they don't change much when the load increases). Servers are on AWS - AWS EC2s.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Hi, were you able to optimize your stack? if yes then how?

Comment: in some way. I tweaked some parameters. I moved to UWSGI. 
Tweaked some apis as well.